# Error while running a PowerShell script as a scheduled task

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script to download and execute an `.exe` file as scheduled task. My script is:

```
$argument = "-Command `"& '(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(‘https://webserver/file.exe’,’%TEMP%\file.exe’); Start-Process “%TEMP%\file.exe'""
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'PowerShell.exe' -Argument $argument
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Principal $principal -Trigger $trigger Register-ScheduledTask "ExampleTask" -InputObject $task -Force
```

If I try to run the script, I get the following error:

```html
At C:\Users\HP\Desktop\1\1.ps1:3 char:50
+ $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" ...
+                                                  ~~
Unexpected token 'NT' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\Folder\script.ps1:5 char:118
+ ... rigger Register-ScheduledTask "ExampleTask" -InputObject $task -Force
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

the reason and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be some odd formatting with strings for the argument and `Register-ScheduledTask` is not on a separate line.

I'd suggest using a here-string:

```
$argument = @'
-Command "& '(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(‘https://webserver/file.exe’,’%TEMP%\file.exe’); Start-Process %TEMP%\file.exe'"
'@
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'PowerShell.exe' -Argument $argument
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Principal $principal -Trigger $trigger
Register-ScheduledTask "ExampleTask" -InputObject $task -Force
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but I get the error
Register-ScheduledTask : Acess Denied.
At C:\Users\Folder\script.ps1:8 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledTask "ExampleTask" -InputObject $task -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-Schedul
   edTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Register-ScheduledTask

Comment: Ensure you are running ISE as Administrator

Comment: Glad to hear it - please mark as the answer if this helped.